# Why do I get a duplicate Id in my MDC SLF4J for two requests?

Tags: java, web, slf4j, mdc

I have a web application. My application deployed by `Tomcat`. I write a `Servlet Filter` for put some data in `MDC` class at `SLF4J` By following code:

`MDC.put("Id", UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

When I run my application for second or third request I get duplicate UUID. This scenario is serial and isn't concurrent. I think there exists a thread pool that thread context don't clear.

Comment: If you put a value with `MDC.put` once you're done with your request you must remove it with `MDC.remove`. This is probably implemented using thread local variables and Tomcat has a thread pool which reuses the treads in different requests. Those reused threads end up using the same thread local values in MDC unless you do the remove invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this structure to guarantee the ID is removed:

```
try {
    MDC.put("Id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    // The rest of your code
} finally {
    MDC.remove("Id");
}
```

(no catch block is necessary). This will guarantee that the `Id` key is removed for this transaction.

Also, of course Tomcat uses a Thread Pool, this is how it manages requests when they are concurrent. Further reading: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html

Comment: Thanks. Your means reason of my problem on `MDC`  is thread pool of `Tomcat`?